# How to deduplicate GCP logs from Logs Explorer?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-logging

I am using GCP Logs explorer to store logging messages from my pipeline.
I need to debug an issue by looking at logs from a specific event. The message of this error is identical except for an event ID at the end.

So for example, the error message is

`event ID does not exist: foo`

I know that I can use the following syntax to construct a query that will return the logs with this particular message structure

```
resource.type="some_resource"
resource.labels.project_id="some_project"
resource.labels.job_id="some_id"
severity=WARNING
jsonPayload.message:"Event ID does not exist:"
```

The last line in that query will then return every log where the message has that string.

I end up with a result like this

```
Event ID does not exist: 1A
Event ID does not exist: 2A
Event ID does not exist: 2A
Event ID does not exist: 3A
```

so I wish to deduplicate that to end up with only

```
Event ID does not exist: 1A
Event ID does not exist: 2A
Event ID does not exist: 3A
```

But I don't see support for this type of deduplication in the [language docs](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/view/logging-query-language)

Due to the amount of rows, I also cannot download a delimited log file.
Is it possible to deduplicate the amount of rows?

Comment: YOu haven't, but you can sink the logs in BigQuery and use a request to deduplicate them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To deduplicate records with BigQuery, follow these steps:

- Identify whether your dataset contains duplicates.
- Create a `SELECT` query that aggregates the desired column using a
  `GROUP BY` clause.
- Materialize the result to a new table using `CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE [tablename] AS [SELECT STATEMENT]`.

You can review the full tutorial [in this link](https://dataform.co/blog/removing-duplicates-bigquery).

To analyze a big quantity of logs, you could route them to BigQuery and analyze the logs using Fluentd.

Fluentd has an output plugin that can use BigQuery as a destination for storing the collected logs. Using the plugin, you can directly load logs into BigQuery in near real time from many servers.

In [this link](https://cloud.google.com/architecture/fluentd-bigquery), you can find a complete tutorial on how to Analyze logs using Fluentd and BigQuery.

To route your logs to BigQuery, first it is necessary to create a sink and route it to BigQuery.

> Sinks control how Cloud Logging routes logs. Using sinks, you can
> route some or all of your logs to supported destinations.
>
> Sinks belong to a given Google Cloud resource: Cloud projects, billing
> accounts, folders, and organizations. When the resource receives a log
> entry, it routes the log entry according to the sinks contained by
> that resource. The log entry is sent to the destination associated
> with each matching sink.
>
> You can route log entries from Cloud Logging to BigQuery using sinks.
> When you create a sink, you define a BigQuery dataset as the
> destination. Logging sends log entries that match the sink's rules to
> partitioned tables that are created for you in that BigQuery dataset.
>
> **1) In the Cloud console, go to the Logs Router page:**
>
> **2) Select an existing Cloud project.**
>
> **3) Select Create sink.**
>
> **4) In the Sink details panel, enter the following details:**
>
> *Sink name:* Provide an identifier for the sink; note that after you create the sink, you can't rename the sink but you can delete it and
> create a new sink.
>
> *Sink description (optional):* Describe the purpose or use case for the sink.
>
> **5) In the Sink destination panel, select the sink service and destination:**
>
> *Select sink service:* Select the service where you want your logs routed. Based on the service that you select, you can select from the
> following destinations:
>
> *BigQuery table:* Select or create the particular dataset to receive the routed logs. You also have the option to use partitioned tables.
>
> For example, if your sink destination is a BigQuery dataset, the sink
> destination would be the following:
>
> ```
> bigquery.googleapis.com/projects/PROJECT_ID/datasets/DATASET_ID
> ```
>
> Note that if you are routing logs between Cloud projects, you still
> need the appropriate destination permissions.
>
> **6) In the Choose logs to include in sink panel, do the following:**
>
> In the Build inclusion filter field, enter a filter expression that
> matches the log entries you want to include. If you don't set a
> filter, all logs from your selected resource are routed to the
> destination.
>
> To verify you entered the correct filter, select Preview logs. This
> opens the Logs Explorer in a new tab with the filter prepopulated.
>
> **7) (Optional) In the Choose logs to filter out of sink panel, do the following:**
>
> In the Exclusion filter name field, enter a name.
>
> In the Build an exclusion filter field, enter a filter expression that
> matches the log entries you want to exclude. You can also use the
> sample function to select a portion of the log entries to exclude. You
> can create up to 50 exclusion filters per sink. Note that the length
> of a filter can't exceed 20,000 characters.
>
> **8) Select Create sink.**

More information about **Configuring and managing sinks** [here](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/export/configure_export_v2#console).

To review details, the formatting, and rules that apply when routing log entries from Cloud Logging to BigQuery, please [follow this link](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/export/bigquery).